# Не могу установить Visual Stuido Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Раньше был VS, но перестал работать(пытался переустановить, но не вышло), решил установить VS Code и при запуске загрузки появляется ошибка. Уже пытался переустановить comctl32.dll, werui.dll, но все равно не запускается. Пожалуйста помогите, нигде не могу найти решение проблемы.
[image]

Comment: windows не старая?

Comment: у меня windows 10

Comment: Я бы установил все обновления